# Web-Based Application using Java Socket and jsf

Tags: java, sockets, jsf, java-ee-7

I have been struggling with finding the logic behind creating a web-based app using java sockets (not WebSockets) with JavaEE and jsf.

Upon lengthy research I have only stumbled upon either Web Apps using Spring and WebSockets or JavaEE Console Apps using Java Sockets.(I can use neither)

I have tried to apply the logic of Console App using Java Sockets and tweak it accordingly in my web app, to no avail.

It is pointless posting code cause I have tried many a code from tutorials etc, but it's the logic that I'm stuck with. In other words, I understand the concept when applied to a Console Application but I do not understand for the life of me how to do it in a Web Application.

Comment: You can't use java sockets in a web application from the client. At least not since suppprt for java applets was removed in browsers, so it is useless to persue this. But you can use websockets (a non-java or jsf specific technology) without spring with plain jsf. What I, for the life of me, don't understand is why you think you can't use websockets in a webapp. Or are you not allowed to?

Comment: Yup, the teacher said I am ought to use Java Sockets only .. But giving what you said I guess I will have to break the rules. Thank you for your response ^^

Comment: Now you added this context, I think you completely misunderstood the assignment. There is no breaking any rule since it is not possible. And if it is an assignement from a teacher, please get feedback from the teacher. He/she get's paid to help, we don't. Hint: the teacher most likely means the backend of the webapp (which is plain java, not related to any front-end technology)

Comment: You're right ^^ Thank you again :D